# Generic terms for people on opposite sides of a transaction

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to find 2 terms to represent the people involved in a transaction. The transactions vary in their semantics, so I've had trouble finding a single set of terms. Here are some sample transactions and potential terms:

```
Give a Reward: giver/recipient  
Mete Punishment: giver/recipient  
Assign a Chore: initiator/assignee  
Ask a Favor: requestor/?
```

The 2 terms will be used as variables in software code, and not exposed to users. I'd like them to be as descriptive as possible (x and y would work, but not be very readable), but generic enough to cover all the transaction semantics.

To complicate things, each person may be sending/receiving emails within the transaction, so I'm trying to stay away from "sender/recipient" to avoid confusion. The "recipient" of a request can be the sender of an email.

Some other terms I've thought of:

```
initiator/acceptor  
originator/terminator (kinda creepy)  
requestor/responder (not really precise)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq), "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, I'm writing a novel that happens to be written in Python and is only read by compilers. Seriously, this is a language question where the application happens to be naming something used in a program. I don't see how that makes it any less interesting a question. That said, I will obey the rules and withdraw it.

Comment: Finding circumvention methods to off-topic questions is off-topic as well, I think.

Comment: requestor/grantor

Comment: @Hollister: I learned English mainly through programming, perhaps over two-third of my vocabulary comes from the use in my early progrmmer's life. (As of now, my vocab size is probably around 20,000 words.) My English was polished and improved a lot when I tried to come up with the exactly right words for various little things in my code. I still remember that it was really fun, and could be frustrating at times.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit "specialised", but some people go for [**transactor** and **transactee**](http://www.translatorscafe.com/tcterms/EN/thQuestion.aspx?id=89879)

The reason this is so localised is because it's often meaningless to attempt to differentiate the **parties** to a transaction. Neither necessarily has any specifically different role to the other, except perhaps in those cases where one gives *goods or services*, and the other gives *money*.

Comment: Not bad. I will give this due consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Traditional grammar offers two contrasting pairs: *subject/object* and *agent/patient*.

Comment: Ah...so obvious, I missed it completely! Since `object` is ubiqitous in software, I think I might use the hybrid `agent/subject`.

Comment: Wait, agent and subject are the same. Darn.

Comment: @Hollister  Even more obvious: #1 and #2. Actor1, Actor2.

Comment: That doesn't really help make it much plainer than x and y.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *requester* and *respondent*.

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer's point of view, I would choose the words **requester** and **requestee**. I remember I saw it in Mozilla and perhaps Drupal realms. (Googling "inurl:mozilla requestee" would yield a lot of hits.)

Having said that, I think some folks go with *requester* and others go with *requestor*. I couldn't tell which one is more popular.